# angular directly send $scope parameter from view to service or factory

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-factory

I have a factory and need to call factory from view.
i want to call factory with two parameters.
Is it possible to send $scope from template?

Because, i am using same factory for multiple places.

```
<input name="accnum" ng-blur="myservice.getAccountDetailsToDisplay($scope, accno)" />
```

controller,

```
 $scope.myservice= getAllDetailsService;
```

In service,

```
tellerApp.factory('getAllDetailsService',['$rootScope', '$resource', '$http', '$filter', '$window',  function ($rootScope, $resource, $http, $filter, $window) {
    return{ 
           getAccountDetailsToDisplay: function ($scope, accountnumber) {
           console.log('>>>>>>');   
          }
};      
}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Service should be directly depends on `scope`, they could be
>   indirectly depend on each other. If you pass $scope to the service it will become tightly couple to that specific controller.

Like in your case you only pass `accountnumber`, then service will make an required operation like doing an ajax call or fetching data from somewhere.

**Factory**

```
tellerApp.factory('getAllDetailsService', ['$rootScope', '$resource', '$filter', '$window', function($rootScope, $resource, $http, $filter, $window) {
    return {
        getAccountDetailsToDisplay: function(accountnumber) {
            return $http.get('/getAccountDetails?accountnumber=' + accountnumber).then(function(res) {
                //here you could do your addtional operation on data.
                return res.data; //giving access to data
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.myservice= getAllDetailsService
//this line will ensure updation in scope
$scope.myservice.accountDetailsToDisplay = getAllDetailsService.accountDetailsToDisplay;
```

**Markup**

```
 <input name="accnum" ng-blur="myservice.getAccountDetailsToDisplay(accno)"/>
```

Likewise in above code I didn't use `$scope` as parameter, service method will only return whatever data is fetched from the service, And whoever the use the service method can get only data return by service. After getting data from service controller modify the scope in its own context.

Comment: I can able to send $scope from controller, but is there any way from template?

Comment: @vishnu I'm updating answer..what is proper way of doing it..passing $scope to service makes you code tightly couple

Comment: @vishnu Yes, you can pass scope object from template, however I would not recommend it. This is answer offers better approach.

Comment: @pankajparkar No, I don't think passing scope into service is right approach at all. Service layer should not depend on presentation layer.

Comment: @pankajparkar Read my first comment carefully.

Answer (score 0):

definitely, $scope is inner context of the controllers, so you don't need to use it in any other places.
If you want to use factory, you should write like this:

```
tellerApp.factory('getAllDetailsService',['$rootScope', '$resource', '$http', '$filter', '$window',  function ($rootScope, $resource, $http, $filter, $window) {
    return{ 
           getAccountDetailsToDisplay: function (accountnumber) {
           console.log('>>>>>>');   
    }
  };      
}]);
```

and in your controller you invoke methods of your factory:

```
$scope.someMethod = getAllDetailsService.getAccountDetailsToDisplay;
```

and on your view:
`<input name="accnum" ng-blur="myservice.someMethod(accno)" />`